# RewriteMap problem in .htaccess

Tags: rewritemap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

I need to do one change in mywebsite. i have two websites. i want to redirect some of the page from website1.com to website2.com based on one mapping file. that mapping file will be on txt file in which the mapping will be in this way like -   /page1.html www.website2.com/page1.html  and so on... i dont want to put rewrite rule in this mapping file. can anybody help me how i can modify the .htaccess file for this.

thanks..

Answer (score 1):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

has a fairly good example.